# Fill in boolean field in a form

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a login form which checks if the user selected "remember me" and if the condition is met, it will automatically fill in the email field.

This is my Form object:

```
val loginForm = Form(
tuple(
  "email" -> email,
  "password" -> text(minLength = 3),
  "remember" -> boolean
  )
)
```

There may be a KV pair stored in the session (`"remember" -> email: String`). I have a working function which returns this email as an `Option[String]`.

This is the function which renders the login page. `views.html.login` is a Template that accepts a Form object and an optional `message: String` which is used for relaying any authentication errors.

```
def login = Action {
    request => {
      logRequest(request)
      if (UserInfo.isAuth(request.session)) {
        Redirect(routes.Application.index())
      }
      else {
        val email = UserInfo.getRememberedEmail(request.session)
        if (email.isDefined) {
          Ok(views.html.login(loginForm.fill(email.get, "", true)))
        }
        else {
          Ok(views.html.login(loginForm))
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I think the problem occurs at `Ok(views.html.login(loginForm.fill(email.get, "", true)))`. When checking the form for errors, this is what I found:

> {"remember":["error.boolean"]}

Comment: Could you share the code of your template? Also, which version of Play are you using? I just tried a minimal example that mimics your setup and it seems to work correctly.